# Field Class Dependencies

Tags: 7, entities, theming

The question is pretty straightforward. How can I add a class on field A, if field B is empty? I can not find any module does this feature. The [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) does not have the class feature too. Can this done by programmatically? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution here is is to use [`template_preprocess_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) function. In your **template.php** add a `MYTHEME_preprocess_field` function and perform a check on the node's field value to determine a class that you set in the `classes_array` variable.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  //Add a new CSS class to field_MYHIDDEN_FIELD
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_MYHIDDEN_FIELD') {

    //Check field_MYCHECKED_FIELD for an empty value
    $new_class = (!isset($node->field_MYCHECKED_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? 'mytheme-field-novalue' : 'mytheme-field-value';
    $variables['classes_array'][] = $new_class;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it should stay `[0]` if your field only accepts one value. The example code sets the class `mytheme-field-novalue` when there's no value set in the `field_MYFIELD` field. For title field, you can check the `$node->title` property.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted my questions. Here are my questions:
1. If I want to make the statement for “if not empty”, where should I change? change the “[0]” to “[1]”?
2. If I want to make the statement for title field, what do I need to replace with “field_MYFIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE]?

Comment: If you want to reverse the logic, just drop the `!`operator in front of the `isset` function call.

Comment: sorry Shawn, i still not clear where to put the 2nd field and new class. Please see my updated question above.

Comment: I updated the answer to elaborate on what I think you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I would use states for something like this:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states

Answer (score 1):

Another more pure UI route is to use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), Views "No Results" and View "Rewriting" and either the [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) or ctools Content Panels to construct the node view.

I haven't tested this, but it will look something like this:

1. Create a content view filtering by node and published value
2. Add fields B and A (in that order)
3. Set Field A to "Exclude from Display"
4. Configure field B's "No results behavior" to render something like `<span class="b_empty">[field_a]</span>` but set the "Rewrite Results" to  `<span class="b_has_data">[field_a]</span><span>[field_b]</span>` Here, field B is doing all the heavy lifting, empty or not.
5. Using EVA, you can then attach that result to your node's field display as you need.